# Установка libksba на mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew

Хочу поставить libksba через homebrew.

```
brew install libksba
==> Downloading ftp:/ /ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2
```

Скачивание не происходит… Может кто сталкивался с этим и может как то можно самому поставить?

Comment: Только что попробывал, все утановилось. Может у Вас локальная трабла?

Comment: Ну если у вас все нормально скачалось и установилось, то скорее всего проблемы у меня ) Я просто попробовал скачать напрямую файл с ftp и у меня ничего не вышло…

Comment: Скачать выложить? )

Comment: @Bimawa это было бы замечательно !

Comment: Да как два байта передать: http://cl.ly/2K2l0B2s3K0b

Comment: спасибо вам !!!